# Assembly 8086 - how to move object

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm new to assembler 8086, I need your help. I've drawn a square, I can't move it with the keys on my keyboard. I would like to create a "pong". I enclose the code below :

"some words in french language"

```
.model small
.data

h db 'je monte',10,13,'$'
b db 'je descends',10,13,'$'
coorx dw ?
coory dw ?

.code

main proc 

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ah, 0   ; set display mode function.
mov al, 13h ; mode 13h = 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
int 10h     ; set it!

mov al,2
mov cx, 10  ;col
mov dx, 10  ;row
mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel

CALL carre


mov al,1
int 21h

cmp al,38h
je haut

cmp al,32h
je baisse

jmp fin

haut:


baisse:



fin:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

endp main


carre proc


colcount:
inc cx
int 10h
cmp cx, 20
JNE colcount

mov cx, 10  ; reset to start of col
inc dx      ;next row
cmp dx, 20
JNE colcount 

mov coorx,cx
mov coory,dx


ret    

carre endp
```

Thanks for all

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: `mov al,1`: you probably meant `mov ah,1`